# Sharing a Constant value between two Javascript files

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, async.js

I'm new to JS and Node in general.  I'm trying to use Puppeteer to simply get the text value of a

tag and save it to a constant.  I'm then trying to use the value in a 'base' class (index.js) where my Mocha tests live. For some reason, I'm struggling. I'm using async.

My file structure is:

[image]

Here is my Puppeteer script:

```js
//customerChoices.js
module.exports = async(page) => {

  const frame = page.frames().find(frame => frame.name() === 'iframe');

  const saveYourChoicesButton = await frame.$('body > div > div > div > form > footer > div > button.permissions-block__submit');
  await saveYourChoicesButton.click({});

  await page.waitForSelector('.page-title');
  const confirmationMessageText = await frame.$eval('.submission-response__copy > p', e => e.textContent);

return confirmationMessageText

};
```

Here is my index.js script where I try to import the constant confirmationMessageText and use it in a test:

```js
const confMessage = require('./test/uiTests/customerChoices');
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const _ = require('lodash');
const chai = require('chai');

describe('Update customer choices', function() {

      it('test all customer choices', async function() {
        const url = _.get(url, `${env}`);
        await page.goto(url);

        await customerChoices(page);
        const cm = awaitCustomerChoices(page);
        expect(cm).to.equal('Thank you. Your choices have been updated.');
      expect(cm).to.equal('Thank you. Your choices have been updated.');
        console.log(confirmationMessageText);
      });
```

I'm unclear why confirmationMessageText is "Thank you. Your choices have been updated.' from the Puppeteer script but 'undefined' from within index.js?

In case it's useful, my package.json looks like:

```js
"engines": {
  "node": ">=6"
},
"dependencies": {
  "chai": "^4.1.2",
  "lodash": "^4.17.10",
  "mocha": "^5.2.0",
  "moment": "^2.22.2",
  "newman": "^4.0.1",
  "puppeteer": "^1.6.2",
  "yargs": "^12.0.1",
  "express": "^4.16.4",
  "supertest": "^3.3.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
  "express": "^4.16.4",
  "supertest": "^3.3.0"
}
}
```

Comment: It's unclear from you code where customerChoices came from, considering that you expected module export to be confMessage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`module.exports` shouldn't be changed asynchronously, especially if it's supposed to be changed on function call. CommonJS modules are evaluated once, `confMessage` is `async(page) => {...}` function.

The function should just return the result:

```
module.exports = async(page) => {
  ...
  return confirmationMessageText;
};
```

And used like:

```
const cm = await customerChoices(page);
```

Comment: thank you for the response. I tried to make the question clearer, apologies. I tried your suggestion but the const is still 'undefined' in the index.js

Comment: In your code cm` is not defined. If the function returns undefined, `await`ed value will be undefined.

Comment: yes, apologies I was rushing ;) thank you for explaining, my understanding is growing.

Comment: Glad you sorted this out.